# C++ duplicating a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax for duplicating a pointer.

How would I make `theVar2=theVar`?

```
Struct MyStructureType {
    double* theVar2;
}

MyStructureType* myStruct;
double* theVar;

theVar = malloc(sizeof(double));


myStruct->theVar2 = theVar; //segfaults
```

Comment: Why do you use `malloc()` instead of `new` in C++?

Comment: Please post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you sure you allocated some valid buffer and assigned its address to `myStruct` in your actual code?

Comment: In C++ a->b means (*a).b, thus here since myStruct is not initialised it will segfault.

Answer (score 5):

Fist allocate memory for `MyStructureType`, then use the `data member` in it.

```
MyStructureType* myStruct = new MyStructureType();
double* theVar = new double();
myStruct->theVar2 = theVar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a variable to some sensible value before you use its value. You haven't set `myStruct` to any sensible value. So don't use it yet.

You don't have any instance of `theVar2` yet. It's a member of a structure, but no instances of that structure exist yet. You can do this:

```
MyStructureType myStruct;
myStruct.theVar2 = theVar;
```

Once an instance of `MyStructureType` *exists*, you can set its `theVar2` member.

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize `myStruct` before you can indirect through it.

```
MyStructurType *myStruct = new MyStructureType;
```

Answer (score 1):

Few points regarding your code:

1. Wrong usage of `malloc`: `malloc` returns a `void *` and before using it you should always cast it like this:

   `double *myptr = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double));`
2. Trying to use `myStruct` before initializing it: You have declared `myStruct` to be a pointer to your structure, and you need to initialize it before you can use it. Your code should look like this:

Using `malloc` here, you can/should use `new`. Other answers demonstrate it already.

```
Struct MyStructureType {
        double* theVar2;
    }

MyStructureType* myStruct;
double* theVar;

myStruct = (MyStructureType*) malloc(sizeof(MyStructureType));
theVar = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double));

myStruct->theVar2 = theVar;
```

Comment: Oh duh. #2 makes sense. Thanks